# pyspark replace negative value to zero

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I may want to asking help about replacing the negative value from different between the timestamp to zero. Running on python3 on spark. Here is my code:

code:

```
timeFmt = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
time_diff_1 = when((col("time1").isNotNull()) &
                       (col("time2").isNotNull()),                      
                       (unix_timestamp('time2', format=timeFmt) - unix_timestamp('time1', format=timeFmt)) / 60
                      ).otherwise(lit(0))

time_diff_2 = when((col("time2").isNotNull()) & 
                       (col("time3").isNotNull()),                       
                       (unix_timestamp('time3', format=timeFmt) - unix_timestamp('time2', format=timeFmt)) / 60
                      ).otherwise(lit(0))

time_diff_3 = when((col("time3").isNotNull()) &                           
                       (col("time4").isNotNull()),                       
                       (unix_timestamp('time4', format=timeFmt) - unix_timestamp('time3', format=timeFmt)) / 60
                      ).otherwise(lit(0))

df = (df      
      .withColumn('time_diff_1', time_diff_1)      
      .withColumn('time_diff_2', time_diff_2)
      .withColumn('time_diff_3', time_diff_3)
     )


df = (df
      .withColumn('time_diff_1', when(col('time_diff_1') < 0, 0).otherwise(col('time_diff_1')))
      .withColumn('time_diff_2', when(col('time_diff_2') < 0, 0).otherwise(col('time_diff_2')))
      .withColumn('time_diff_3', when(col('time_diff_3') < 0, 0).otherwise(col('time_diff_3')))
     )
```

when I run the above code, I get error.
Here is the error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1083.showString. :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 56.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.3 in stage 56.0 (TID 7246, fxhclxcdh8.dftz.local, executor 21): org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: failed to compile:
>   org.codehaus.janino.JaninoRuntimeException: Code of method
>   "apply_9$(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/InternalRow;)V"
>   of class
>   "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection"
>   grows beyond 64 KB /* 001 */ public java.lang.Object generate(Object[]
>   references) { /* 002 */   return new
>   SpecificUnsafeProjection(references); /* 003 */ } /* 004 */ /* 005 */
>   class SpecificUnsafeProjection extends
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeProjection { /* 006 */
>   /* 007 */   private Object[] references; /* 008 */   private boolean
>   evalExprIsNull; /* 009 */   private boolean evalExprValue; /* 010 */
>
>   private boolean evalExpr1IsNull; /* 011 */   private boolean
>   evalExpr1Value; /* 012 */   private java.text.DateFormat formatter5;
>   /* 013 */   private java.text.DateFormat formatter8; /* 014 */
>
>   private java.text.DateFormat formatter12; /* 015 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter13; /* 016 */   private
>   UTF8String.IntWrapper wrapper; /* 017 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter15; /* 018 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter18; /* 019 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter19; /* 020 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter23; /* 021 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter26; /* 022 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter27; /* 023 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter30; /* 024 */   private
>   java.text.DateFormat formatter32; ........

Anybody can help?

Comment: Please provide a small [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-dataframe-examples).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easier way is just to write a simple UDF(User Defined Function) and apply it on the column you want. here is a sample code to do this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

correctNegativeDiff = f.udf(lambda diff: 0.0 if diff < 0.0 else diff, DoubleType())

df = df.withColumn('time_diff_1', correctNegativeDiff(df.time_diff_1))\
       .withColumn('time_diff_2', correctNegativeDiff(df.time_diff_2))\
       .withColumn('time_diff_3', correctNegativeDiff(df.time_diff_3))
```

Comment: Thank you, this code have helped me solve the problem, just have a small issue, it not return 0 but null.

Comment: You're welcome, I think it's because of  LongType(). change it to IntegerType() or FloatType() may solve your issue!

Comment: I have change to double type as my value is in double type, but still get null instead of 0. Thank you.

Comment: change it like this may solve that: `f.udf(lambda diff: 0 if diff <= 0 else diff, DoubleType())`

Comment: If you are using DoubleType, you should also feed double types. Changing the udf as follows should get rid of the null in your case: `f.udf(lambda diff: 0.0 if diff < 0.0 else diff, DoubleType())`